# Azure Pricing, "Medium"(Azure price calculator) or "Standard/S2"(New Azure Portal)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We use a "Medium" instance for our production site, and on the old portal. I have just noticed that on the new portal there is no "Small", "Medium" or "Large" any more, but rather Standard/S2, which seems to be a new name for "Medium" as it is the same spec. However the price is very different(less). Perhaps this is because I am a MSDN subscriber and the new portal reflects my real price to pay, rather than the calculator which is the regular price?

So is "Medium" Website instance naming history now? I have noticed that MS is going towards Standard/S..n and Basic/S...n for its services. I just had not realised that they had done it for Websites.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since April 2014, Microsoft Introduced two different tiers for Virtual Machines - Basic and Standard. With different characteristics and prices of course. The details around different tiers and prices are listed [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/).

If you go for Azure Web Sites, apparently there only a "Standard" tier VMs are utilized, thus the "Standard" in the name.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Azure websites do have "Basic" as well, but with less features such as no "Austoscaling". We use "Basic" for our test instances, while using "Standard" for the Live instances.